# Recoding 0-3 values

Tags: stata

I have speech data set so here is how it is coded now:

```
Hypernasality (0-3)
Speech understandibility (0-3)
Speech Acceptability (0-3)
```

Where 0 is good 3 is severe deviation from normal speech.

```
Hypnasality (0 and 1)
Audible Air Emission (0 and 1)
```

Where 0 is none and 1 is yes

I recoded my data this way:

```
foreach j in speechunderstandibility speechacceptability hypernasality { 
recode `j' (0 = 3) (3 = 0) (1 = 2) (2 = 1), gen (`j'_1)
}

foreach j in hyponasality audibleemission {
recode `j' (0 = 1) (1 = 0), gen (`j'_1)
}
```

However, when I run my regression it gives me counter-intuitive results. 
My dependent variable is speech outcome and beta of interest is cleft severity. 
Results after recoding would say" Cleft severity improves speech but cleft surgery decreases it"

If I leave it the way it is coded then all 5 outcomes mentioned above have different outcomes.

I need them to go in one direction so I can build a summary index.

Comment: I can't see a programming question here. Your problem seems to be that you don't understand your results. That's at most a statistical problem although it's not clear how anyone can help without subject-matter expertise on what makes sense. Nor is it obvious that mushing outcomes together will improve anything. You probably need to talk this through locally with someone who can ask lots of questions about your aims and data.

Comment: I edited out various personal comments, which don't make your question clearer or more important to anyone else.

Comment: Note that 3 - _x_ reverses _x_ in 0 to 3 and more generally _U - x_ reverses _x_ in 0 to _U_, so `recode` is not the simplest way to do it.

Comment: I am working with my advisor on this issue. I am using the above mentioned 5 parameters and build an Anderson Index to capture overall speech outcomes. If I do not recode, then 2/5 parameters will give counterintuitive results. If I do recode then 3/5 parameters will give counterintuitive results. If I do not recode, what else can I use?

Comment: To repeat: This is in my view off-topic. You want statistical advice. That's fine on Cross Validated or Statalist, but not here. Besides, there is little chance of people being in your field and being able to advise for or against an "Anderson index". FWIW, your different measure are, statistically, not parameters but variables.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a raw data issue. I would make sure that all the data points were entered correctly, because at some stage of data entry, the entry of the 0-3 may have gotten mixed up. So it may be a mix up during data-entry.

Secondly, if you're really sure of the data entry (this sounds like a data entry issue to me, or like Nick Cox says, a data interpretation issue), then perhaps try using "gen" and "replace" commands to recode your variables inside or outside of a loop.

When I have trouble with a looped command, I dissect each part and raw code it.